# How to modify the PATH environment variables in Catalina?

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, path, macos

Some application tells me to add something to the PATH environment variables, I know one way to do this is by creating a file at `~/.zshrc`, but I would like to know where is the file the variable `PATH=...` is stored?

When I typed `echo $PATH` I got:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
```

From the file `/etc/paths` I got:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

So which file appended the additional paths?

---

Reply to the comment:

I got: (forgive me that I changed my user name to `alice`)

```
grep: /Users/alice/.profile: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/environment: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/zsh/zprofile: No such file or directory
grep: /Users/alice/.zshrc: No such file or directory
grep: /Users/alice/.profile: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `grep dotnet ~/.profile /etc/environment /etc/profile /etc/zsh/zprofile ~/.zshrc ~/.profile`.

Comment: Argh, crap. Looks like mac moves some files around. I would also try `grep -R dotnet /etc 2>/dev/null` and `grep dotnet ~/.* 2>/dev/null`. Simply searching for `dotnet`, one of the extra things in your `$PATH`, in all files in `/etc` and any dotfiles in your home dir.

Comment: Great! Could you please post an answer explaining what you found?

Comment: Of course. Whenever you can!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said in [your own self-answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580596/116858), you don't need to know where the `PATH` variable is originally populated.

You may easily add new paths to the `PATH` at either end or beginning, and `zsh` also has a convenient way of removing duplicates.

You may make the `PATH` variable, and the associated `path` array, unique first, by using

```
typeset -U -g PATH path
```

The variables will then *stay* unique by virtue of this command.

To prepend a couple of paths:

```
path=( /new/path1 /new/path2 $path )
```

To append a couple of paths:

```
path=( $path /new/path1 /new/path2 )
```

or,

```
path+=( /new/path1 /new/path2 )
```

The `PATH` variable's value will be updated accordingly.

You may want to do this in your `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile` file, which is sourced automatically by any `zsh` login shell. Doing it in your `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv` file would be unnecessary as that file is sourced by *any type* of `zsh` invocation (and should therefore be kept really short, if it's needed at all; I just set `ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.zsh` in there, for example).

Note that `PATH` is already an environment variable, so exporting it again serves no purpose.

Comment: About `ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.zsh`, if I set this on `/etc/zshenv`, would it be a good idea? (I originally set it on `~/.zshenv`, but this way I will have both `~/.zshenv` and `~/.zsh/`, but I want `~/.zshenv` also in `~/.zsh/` folder)

Comment: @Niing If `/etc/zshenv` sets `ZDOTDIR` to `$HOME/.zsh`, then `~/.zsh/.zshenv` will be read rather than `~/.zshenv` (for all users). Personally I have `~/.zshenv` as a symbolic link to `~/.zsh/.zshenv`.

Answer (score 2):

The file `/etc/zprofile` uses `/usr/libexec/path_helper` to set the default `PATH` and we don't have the source code of it.

The following shows you how to modify user-wise `PATH`:

Create/edit `~/.zprofile` and add the following content:

```
# append to PATH
export PATH="$PATH:.../to/target/bin"

# prepend to PATH
export PATH=".../to/target/bin:$PATH"

# remove duplicate in PATH
typeset -U PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

The following steps show you how to modify system-wise `PATH`:

1. Create a file with the naming convention: priority-appname(e.g. '20200418-vscode', I just use date to make the priority unique) Then store the path you want to add to `PATH` in it.
2. Move that file to `/etc/paths.d/`, done.

**Notice1:** Remember to create a new terminal session to see the change in `echo $PATH`.

Notice2: this method only **appends** your path to `PATH`.